# Selenium Exception: SessionNotCreatedException

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

I just updated to the latest version of Selenium and Gekodriver & when I try running Selenium I get the following exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException

Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{marionette=true, firefoxOptions=org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions@5bfa9431, browserName=firefox, moz:firefoxOptions=org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions@5bfa9431, version=, platform=ANY}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]
```

I don't understand why I keep getting this exception if I've already set `desired capabilities`:

```
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
```

Any ideas?

I ran Selenium thousands of times already but now that I've updated to the latest version I cannot run it at all.

Thanks

Comment: It has nothing to do with desiredCapabilities. You just need to get matching versions of selenium*.jars and geckodriver

Comment: Follow exactly this one: http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/launching-firefox-browser-with-geckodriver-selenium-3

Comment: what is firefox version you are using?

Comment: @Kapil I tried several versions from the latest (54.0.1) version to previous versions but they all failed

Comment: @OmSao Thanks but I believe I have downloaded all the latest jars still no luck

Comment: yes, it happens that there are mismatch.
I am using Firefox54(which is latest), geckodriver 2.31 and selenium 2.33

All is working well.

Comment: what are selenium and geckodriver versions?

Comment: @OmSao where do you find version 2.31 of geckodriver?

Comment: @LittleKevin: Sorry, I was using V1.18 https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Comment: @OmSao and selenium 2.33 where did you download it? Thanks

Comment: Create maven dependency: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java/2.33.0

Comment: @OmSao I did exactly that - I am running v0.18.0 of geckodriver, I added 2.33 selenium to maven but I still get this error (running latest firefox)

Comment: What can I say, if possible, try google chrome browser and it's driver, they are much more stable.

Or, just remember what were the version of FF, Selenium jars and geckodriver which ran successfully last time.

Comment: @OmSao I tried reverting back to a different version of geckodriver (that doesn't produce previous error)  but now the program just keeps running forever without actually launching webdriver

Comment: Can you update the question with your exact code block and full error stack trace along with your Selenium, geckodriver & Firefox browser information?

Comment: @OmSao I am able to use a previous version of Selenium/Geckodriver however then I run into the issue in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45847233/selenium-exception-invalidargumentexception (this is what initially caused me to changed versions)